# Dismiss keyboard when tapped outside of a textview in a scroll view

Tags: ios, swift

The scrollview takes up the whole viewcontroller. A textview is placed in the scrollview. I wish to dismiss the keyboard when the use taps outside of the keyboard.

boostContent is the IBOutlet of the textview.

I've tried the code below and it doesn't work.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.scrollView.endEditing(true)
    boostContent.resignFirstResponder()

}
```

What's the correct solution?

I've also tried self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: boostContent is the name of the textview. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the same view holding your text view.  Wire it up to this:

```
@IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    boostContent.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I think the issue with what you were trying to do is that your `touchesBegan` wasn't being called because it is defined on your `ViewController` and the content view of the scroll view is intercepting the touches.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a tap gesture to your view controller and resign the first responder there. The other way, and I think is a better one, is to use a container view. You put it inside you scrollview and then put all your objects, including the textfield, in the container view.